# Using docks causes corruption on xubuntu

Tags: dock

If I use a dock on xubuntu, I get a screen corruption(https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6CdU.png vs https://i.stack.imgur.com/BArYl.png). Tried with plank and docky.

Any clue?

Comment: Where is the screen corruption?

Comment: For `plank`, use at least version 0.10.1 for proper rendering on screen in Xubuntu (It is working properly at least in 14.04 release). Else, the "thin line" appearing in lower half of your screen may be caused by other things, not surprising to happen in non-LTS regular releases.